# python twitter filter hometimeline

Tags: python, python-twitter

I am writing a function that filter the keyword of my timeline using python-twitter.
I do not know how to filter tweets in my timeline.
should I use GetSearch(term=keyword)?

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(my keys)

timelines = api.GetHomeTimeline()
for lines in timelines:
    print(lines.text)
```

Comment: `[lines.text for lines in timelines if 'your keyword' in lines.text]`, should work, otherwise I'm not sure if the api has a specific method for filtering by keyword

Comment: or if you want to keep the expanded `for`-loop syntax: `for lines in timelines:
    if 'your keyword' in lines.text:
        print(lines.text)`

Comment: could also use python's [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function for each Status in `GetHomeTimeline` list: `print(list(filter(lambda k: 'your keyword' in k,[k.text for k in timelines])))` will return a list of tweets containing the "keyword"